# how to create a regular expression that matches this specific protocol

Tags: regex

I am wondering if it is possible to create a regex that parses a particular protocol
that I am attempting to parse.

Here are the rules.

1. Data comes in a string.
2. '=' character has special meaning. To escape = the data might contain == just like "" in a quoted string.
3. if '=' is followed by a number between 2-5 it indicates that the data that is following is for that channel (2, or 3 or 4 or 5)

Examples

1. sdfasjfasdjfalksjdfaksjdflkajsdlfjasdf //data that is assumed to be for the "current channel
2. =2sjfksdjfaksjdfkasjdfk //whatever follows =2 is for channel 2
3. =2sjdfaksdjf=3sjfkasjdfk //whatever that follows =2 is for channel 2 and whatever that follows is for channel 3
4. fsdfasjfhajsd=2sfdjashdfjashfa=5sfajsdfaksjdf //the initial part is for the current channel, 
   whatever follows =2 is for channel 2, whatever follows =5 is for channel 5
5. Note that == is escaped and should be regarded as an escaped =, as part of data
6. =2=x4 //note that =x4 is for channel 2. which means that if = is followed by a number 2-5 only 
   it means there is a channel switch. otherwise it is just part of the data
7. The only special case here is the end of string where the string ends with an =.
   In this case, we will not know what will be coming down the pipe later so we just have to keep 
   that for later use meaning add that to the incoming buffer, just in case

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a regular language.

Comment: surely there's a regex that will match any string of your protocol. I am not sure if you can use it to "parse". some extensions allow capturing groups, but since there may be many channels in a string you'd have to capture groups inside closures. that's the part I'm not sure if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
/(?:=(?P<channel>[2-5])|^)(?P<data>(?:(?===)==|(?!=(?:[2-5]|\Z)).)*)/ms
```

You'll find the channel in group `channel` (if any) and the rest in the group `data`.

[Demo.](http://regex101.com/r/fU1jD2/3)

Explanation:

```
(?: # first, match a "=" channel...
    =
    (?P<channel>
        [2-5]
    )
| #...or assert position at the start of the string
    ^
)
(?P<data> # next, capture the data in a group
    (?: # repeat the following as often as possible:
        (?= # if there's an escaped "=" ("=="), consume it
            ==
        )
        ==
    |
        (?! # otherwise, if...
            =
            (?: #...the next match doesn't start here...
                [2-5]
            | #...and the string doesn't end with "=" here...
                \Z
            )
        )
        . #...consume a single character
    )*
)
```